# d3js - Bar charts inside graph nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Does anybody know if it is possible to visualize bar charts inside graph nodes in d3js like in this figure?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This sketch sucks, but you can do it with d3. Another words: "Yes, it is possible!"

Comment: Please let me know if you are aware of any code snippet.

Comment: Have you JSON with real data for it or some kind the data emulation? d3 is based on a data. The graphs inside nodes depends of the data and should be created specifically of the data.

Comment: Yes, It depends on your implementation but the basic idea is to target each squares, get their respective boundaries (x, y, width, height) and create a new bar char using those bounds, for each square you will need a new data entry point.